# Trouble making post request in react (axios, front end and node server running on different ports)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I have a mern stack that i'm working on.
I'm making a post request from my SignupForm component.

```html
  handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        // TODO - validate!
        axios
            .post('/auth/signup', {
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password
            })

    }
```

To a post handler in my routes folder here

```html
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    //const { username, password } = req.body

    console.log('signup route hit in auth folder')
    res.end()
    // ADD VALIDATION

})
```

When I use postman to this route
localhost:8080/auth/signup  i get the correct console log,
however my front end is running on 
localhost:3000

I keep getting this error

```
VM1951:1 POST http://localhost:3000/auth/signup 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ VM1951:1
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

How can i combine the front end and back end ports for a full stack application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The request from the client is going to the same host, because the route starts with a slash (`\`)

Your handle submit should look like

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        // TODO - validate!
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:8080/auth/signup', {
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password
            })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me out.  I ended up using a proxy in the package.json to achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a proxy in the package.json file.  Resources i used are:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0t42xBIYIs
and 
https://github.com/thechutrain/mern-passport/blob/master/package.json
and
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development